# react-native i can not run iOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

** BUILD FAILED **

The following commands produced analyzer issues:

```
Analyze /Users/allen/WebstormProjects/untitled/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodeList.c
Analyze /Users/allen/WebstormProjects/untitled/node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/Yoga.c
```

(2 commands with analyzer issues)

The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Install\ Third\ Party /Users/allen/WebstormProjects/untitled/ios/build/Build/Intermediates/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/double-conversion.build/Script-190EE32F1E6A43DE00A8543A.sh
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
Failed to install the requested application
An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/untitled.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
> rm -rf ~/.rncache
> rm -rf node_modules
> yarn install
> react-native run-ios
```

use `yarn install` replace `npm install`. I got the exact same error when using `npm install`, after try `yarn install`, it finally works for me.

my project dependencies:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
"react-native": "0.45.1"
```